# FindAndModify: get newDocument along with info whether doc was inserted or updated

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Using `findAndModify`:

- I need to get the new resulting document
- I need to know if an insert or update was done

  ```
  var newUpdate = {
    $set : newData,
    $setOnInsert: {created_at: new Date()}
  };
  var options = {
    upsert  :true,
    new: true, 
  };
  collectionDriver.findAndModify(colName, query, newUpdate, options, function(err,resultDoc)
  {
        if (err) {
        } else {
        }
  });
  ```

I get the new document, how can I know if an insert/update was happened?

Answer (score 1):

One possible, though not the most efficient way, can be to check for presence of record before issuing the modify command because if you need the new record, then you cannot check if it previously existed.